# Equivalent to Expression.Convert using Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I am currently trying to extent an existing application that uses reflection (ILGenerator) to create a dynamic method.

I currently have an object on the stack, this method needs to convert the object to the same type as 'parameterType'.  I want to provide the same conversion functionality that we get when using Expression.Convert

```
public override void EmitParameterResolution(ILGenerator il, Type parameterType)
{
    // il.Emit - Not sure what to do here...
    // Expression.Convert(obj, parameterType)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [Castclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.castclass.aspx):

```
public override void EmitParameterResolution(ILGenerator il, Type parameterType)
{
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, parameterType);
}
```

You might also think about just [Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call.aspx), put parameterType on the stack after obj and then do something like this:

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(Convert).GetMethod("ChangeType");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, mi);
```

Comment: Note that castclass does not handle value types.  In that case you need unbox, but you have to be careful to unbox the boxed value as the *exact type* it was boxed as.  (You can't unbox an int as a long, for example.)  `ChangeType()` will simplify this somewhat, at the cost of an extra box/unbox operation.  (If you pass a boxed int into to `ChangeType()` and request a long, it will unbox the int, convert it to a long, and box that.  Then you have to unbox the long.)